# Rails 5: redirect if trial period expires

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a controller named `HomeController` with `index` and `show` actions. I want to check if the user subscription has ended and show him a message and redirect to `HomeController#index`.

Currently i am doing it as below

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  before_action :check_if_trial_expired, only: [:index]
  before_action :redirect_if_trial_expired, only: [:show]
 
  protected

  def check_if_trial_expired
    @trial_expired = current_user.trial_expired?
  end

  def redirect_if_trial_expired
    redirect_to home_path if current_user.trial_expired?
  end
end
```

Is there a better way to do this? I want to redirect the user to `HomeController#index` in case a condition satisfies.

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll at least need the `index` and `show` methods defined on the controller; make sure you have them in your routes. I don't think you need to use `before_action` for the index. Also, you can memoize `trial_expired` if it is an expensive operation.

```rb
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :redirect_if_trial_expired, only: [:show]

  def index; end

  def show; end
 
  private

  def redirect_if_trial_expired
    redirect_to home_path if current_user.trial_expired?
  end
end
```

Comment: Show your routes. Make sure `home_path` handled by `index` action and not `show`